# Why is $\sin(x) < |h|$ when we prove continuity of $\sin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I was just proving the continuity of the function $\sin(x)$ with $|f(x_0+h) - f(x_0) |$ and in the proof I had to use the fact that $\sin^2(h) + \cos^2(h) = 1 \iff \cos^2(h) - 1 = -\sin^2(h) \iff (\cos(h) - 1) (\cos(h) +1) = -\sin^2(h) \\\iff (\cos(h) -1) =\frac{-\sin^2(h)}{\cos(h) +1 } \iff |\cos(h) -1| = |\frac{-\sin^2(h)}{\cos(h) +1 }|\leq|\frac{\sin^2(h)}{\cos(h) +1 }|<(...\text{we use the fact that $|\sin(h)|<|h|$}...)
<\frac{h^2}{1}$

We used this because when we use this definition of continuity and we want to prove that the sine function is continuous, we get to: $|\sin(x)\cos(h)+\sin(h)\cos(x)- \sin(x)| = |\sin(x)(\cos(h) - 1)+ \cos(x)\sin(h)|$

and then if I am not mistaking we can: ...$< |\sin(x)h^2+\cos(x)h | = h|\sin(x)h+\cos(x)| <(\text{...we set h < 1}...$) $<h(\sin(x)\cdot1+\cos(x)| < \epsilon\iff h< \frac{\epsilon}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)} ...\text{because $|h|<\delta$, we then set...}\implies\delta:=\frac{\epsilon}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}$

I do not understand how do we get to $\frac{h^2}{1}$ .

Is my overall reasoning about this proof correct? The idea should be, but I might have some missed understanding, so if there are any mistakes.

Comment: @Asher2211 I see so can we use the Cauchy-schwarz here to get: $|\sin^2(h)\cdot\frac{1}{\cos(h)+1} |\leq |\sin^2(h)| \cdot |\frac{1}{\cos(h)+1} |$.

And then we somehow say $|\frac{1}{\cos(h)+1} | \leq 1$ , here is where my understanding fails.

Comment: $\mid \frac{1}{\cos(h)+1} \mid \leq 1$ is true  because $cos(h)$ is positive when $h$ is close to $0$.

Comment: Is $\delta$ or $h$ limited?  If so, what is the relationship?

Comment: There is a "axiomatic way" to define trigonometric functions (see Spivak, Calculus)  that is compatible with  all the identities known from basic geometry courses. This approach defines sin or cosine as an integral (similar to the way one can define $\log$) Within this framework then it continuity and all the results about differentiability follows. In a more elementary way, one uses the basic high school trigonometry to get an understanding of basic relation between arcs and length of triangles inscribed in a circle (including $|\sin h|\leq |h|$.

Comment: I've no idea how to answer the question asked. But I do think such a proof is unnecessary, as it's easier to prove sine is differentiable. Then "differentiable implies continuous" gives us the result.